# Check in relationship if a column is true, Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have 2 tables: roles & users.

In users I have role_id, and I want to check if that role has a column "access_admin_area" on true. If true, I am using a middleware.

```
Gate::define('admin', function ($user) {
   return !empty($user->roles()->where('access_admin_area', true)->first());
});
```

**From User model:**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column roles.user_id does not exist↵LINE 1: select * from "roles" where "roles"."user_id" = $1 and "role..

Comment: If you change your `roles()` relationship from `return $this->hasOne(Role::class);` to `return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);` Your foreign-key and local key will be interpreted the other way around :)

Comment: hm, Not sure why, but not I get an empty array, and every user has a role..

Comment: I have to add "  return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');  " , and it works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error describes the issue pretty nicely here - the hasOne relationship method inside your User model expects the Role table row to have a user_id column that specifies a foreign key referencing the user table id column.

If I was you, I'd rather use hasMany relationhip between your User and Role model in this use case, since I expect your users and roles should have a many-to-many relationship

check out the many-to-many relationship eloquent and database structure in the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: So obvious..thanks! But in my case a user can have only 1 role. (Admin, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked like this way:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id' , 'role_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change **hasOne** to **belongsTo**
then you can a simpler way to save yourselve from many where clauses in your controlleer is by creating another relationship with eg name as **rolewithadminaccess**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function rolewithadminaccess()
{
    return $this->roles()->where('access_admin_area', true)->limit(1);
}
```

then you can do this in your controller

```
return $user->rolewithadminaccess;
```